# How do I ommit the numerical qualifer for my product in iOS's In-App Purchase dialog?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase, grammar

My app is selling virtual currency like many other iOS games. The title of one of my virtual currency products is "30 credits". When iOS pops up the dialog to pay for my product, it shows a grammatically incorrect sentence. The dialog's description says "one 30 credits". The "one" should be omitted to be grammatically correct.

[image]

```
SKProduct* product = response.products.firstObject;
SKMutablePayment* payment = [SKMutablePayment paymentWithProduct:product];
payment.applicationUsername = [Me instance].user.username;
payment.quantity = 1;
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
```

I've tried commenting out the line that sets the quanity, hoping that internally SKProduct would behave differently, but the grammar remains incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not technically incorrect since you are really purchasing one instance of the "30 credits" product.

There is no way to change the wording. Your only option would be to rename your product so the resulting message works better for you. Perhaps put the product name in quotes.

Comment: I'm assuming this is part of why games always sell one "barrel of coins" one "mountain of coins" etc.